# Does Apache do a DNS lookup when myserver.com in Allow from myserver.com is in /etc/hosts?

Tags: apache-2.2, domain-name-system

The apache documentation states a DNS lookup will be performed when the Allow from (or Deny from) clause contains a domain name (e.g Allow from myserver.com). What if the domain name and IP is listed /etc/hosts?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apache use nsswitch. If IP address in /etc/hosts then use /etc/hosts information.

Comment "10.0.2.15      localhost" in /etc/hosts:

```
curl 10.0.2.15
16:48:41.505697 IP 10.0.2.15.43281 > 10.0.2.2.53: 11646+ PTR? 15.2.0.10.in-addr.arpa. (40)
16:48:41.506336 IP 10.0.2.2.53 > 10.0.2.15.43281: 11646 NXDomain* 0/1/0 (99)
```

Uncomment "10.0.2.15      localhost" in /etc/hosts:

```
curl 10.0.2.15
```

but performance still decreases:

```
% time     seconds  usecs/call     calls    errors syscall
------ ----------- ----------- --------- --------- ----------------
  0.88    0.028002          37       752           getsockname
```